Collider that appears on its own
Sometimes there is a capsule collider that shows itself, even though I haven't added the capsule collider and there is no collider in the inspect view. I try to lower the model, but it keeps rising. This makes some components like NavMeshAgent not work.


This is a nav mesh agent.

That's not a capsule collider. That looks like just a gizmo that indicate the NavMeshAgent's height and radius. Do you have configured those already? You collapsed all components in your screeshot, so we don't know what settings you're using.
The height and radius are used by the agent to determine if they can get past an obstacle on the NavMesh. Those two values essentially define the space your agent occupies / needs.

Oh yes, you are right, it is because of NavMeshAgent. Thanks for helping me solve this.
